# Connection Pooling and Auditing

Tags: mysql, postgresql, connection-pooling, audit

The main issue is that I want to audit user behavior (with triggers), but we are currently using connection pooling with our database, so don't have their username/id directly inside the db.

1. I understand that there is an EXECUTE AS LOGIN function in MSSQL Server. Is there something similar in MySQL or Postgres?
2. Do I have other options, other than auditing from the ORM and not the database?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PostgreSQL you can use [`SET ROLE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-set-role.html) or [`SET SESSION AUTHORIZATION`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-set-session-authorization.html) but you must have the role already defined in the database.

You can choose which of them fits better your needs.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to SET ROLE there is another possibly useful option [SET APPLICATION_NAME](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-logging.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-LOGGING-WHAT). This doesn't have to be the application - as long as your app's usernames fit in 64 characters it's very useful for that.